# How to initialize double matrix with NaN element?

Tags: c++, c++11, nan

in my code I have a matrix of double like this:

```
double * * matrix=new double * [10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
    matrix[i]=new double[10];
```

I want to have *NaN value* in every cell of this matrix when I initialize it, is it possible to do automatically or the only solution is:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        matrix[i][j]=nan("");
```

Is it possible to infer that when the matrix will costruct, it doesn't use the default constructor of double that insert, for every matrix[i][j], 0.0 value but insert nan("")?

Comment: Please, don't code with low level pointers like this. https://godbolt.org/g/qMVXHH

Comment: This isn't C... please use `std::vector`...

Comment: @samuelnj why isn’t c (++)? Why I can’t use low level pointers?

Comment: You shouldn't use low level pointers because they are easy to make bugs, and there are much better alternatives in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double` doesn't have a default constructor, i.e. `double` values are uninitialized by default.

To avoid explicitly implementing the loops, you can use `std::vector` :

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(10, std::vector<double>(10, nan("")));
```

or:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
...
vector<vector<double>> matrix(10, vector<double>(10, nan("")));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, **strongly avoid** using raw pointers in C++ yourself - it's almost always a bad idea. If there's no container class that fits, use `std::unique_ptr`. So your code becomes:

```
auto matrix = std::make_unique<double* []>(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)  {
    matrix.get()[i]= std::make_unique<double []>(10);
}
```

This code is still not what you want. It's usually not a good idea to create your NxN matrix using N calls to `new`, or n constructions of a vector. Make a single allocation of NxN doubles, and then either wrap it in a class `MyMatrix` which supports a 2-parameter square-brace operator, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
class MyMatrix { 
   // etc. etc
   double const T& operator[](size_type i, size_type j) const { return data_[i*n + j]; }
   double T& operator[](size_type i, size_type j) { return data_[i*n + j]; }
}
```

or (not-recommended) have the pointers point into the single-allocation region:

```
size_t n = 10;
auto matrix_data = std::make_unique<double []>(n * n);
auto matrix = std::make_unique<double* []>(n);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)  {
    matrix.get()[i] = matrix_data.get() + i * n;
}
```

in each of these cases you can later use `std::fill` to set all matrix values to NaN, outside of any loop.

The last example above can also be transformed into using vectors (which is probably a better idea than just the raw pointers if you're not using your own class):

```
size_t n = 10;
auto matrix_data = std::vector<double>(n * n);
auto matrix = std::vector<double*>(n);
for(auto& row : matrix) {
    auto row_index = std::dist(row, matrix.begin());
    row = &matrix_data[row_index * n];
}
```

Again, I don't recommend this - it's still a C-like way to enable a `my_matrix[i][j]` syntax, while using a wrapper class gets you `my_matrix[i,j]` without needing extra storage, with  initialization to NaN or another value (in the constructor), and without following two pointers each time you access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use statically sized arrays you would be better off using `std::array`. For easier use of multi-dimenstional `std::array` you can use a template alias

```
template <class T, size_t ROW, size_t COL>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, COL>, ROW>;
```

You can set the values in the matrix with `std::array::fill`, e.g.

```
Matrix<double, 3, 4> m = {};
m.fill(42.0);
```

You can also create a compile-time constant matrix object initialized with a default value to skip the initialization at runtime with a simple `constexpr`function.

```
template<typename T, size_t R, size_t C>
constexpr auto makeArray(T&& x) {
    Matrix<T,R,C> m = {};
    for(size_t i=0; i != R; ++i) {
        for(size_t j=0; j != C; ++j) {
            m[i][j] = std::forward<T>(x);
        }
    }
    return m;
}

auto constexpr m = makeArray<double, 3,4>(23.42);
```

I am going to repeat the advice given to prefer C++ constructs over C constructs. They are more type-safe and IMHO almost always more convenient to use, e.g. passing `std::array` objects as parameters is not different from any other objects. If you are coming from a C background and have no further C++ experience, I would recommend to read some tutorial text that does not first introduce C, e.g. [The Tour of C++,](https://isocpp.org/tour)